# Mocking User.Identity in ASP.NET WebApi Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

How can you mock the User.Identity [for unit testing] of the ASP.NET WebApi ApiControllers?

**Note:**

Some of the controller methods returns are `aync [Task]` which run on a different thread

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162534/mock-iidentity-and-iprincipal

Comment: I would suggest using in-memory http server for integration testing. You can insert delegating handler into the pipeling to handle authentication. This [article](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/) might help.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar for an MVC controller test. What I ended up doing was attaching a fake HttpContext to the controller and then attaching a GenericPrincipal to the fake context.

```
var myController = new SomeController();
var context = A.Fake<HttpContextBase>();
ControllerContext context = new ControllerContext( new RequestContext( context, new RouteData() ), myController );
myController.ControllerContext = context;
myController.HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal( new GenericIdentity( "bob" ), null );
```

I'm using FakeItEasy so the syntax for generating the fakes may be different for you.

Comment: WebApi ApiCOntroller uses HttpControllerContext and does not have an HttpContext property